# Are DefType statments considered Bad Practice?

Tags: vb6, coding-style

I want your thoughts on why or (why not) this statement should (or should not) be used.

Since this is a little subjective, here is my criteria:
Upvotes given for concrete reasons (as opposed to unreasoned opinion). Final answer accepted will be the most comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a well-crafted program, [Defxxx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263421(VS.60).aspx) statements are pointless, because all variables and functions will be explicitly typed.

Except for one case: DefObj A-Z, in conjunction with [Option Explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266183(VS.60).aspx), makes it (practically) impossible for any untyped or undeclared variable, function, or member to exist in your code, and makes anything that would wind up as a Variant stand out in sharp relief.

DefObj A-Z is the suspenders to Option Explicit's belt.

Comment: Side note: In my boredom, I said unto myself "Yea, I shall commit a most grievous coding party foul and us Extended ASCII variables to defeat this new trick."  But guess what? Even though A-Y only covers A through Y A-Z actually covers *everything* extended ASCII included.

Comment: +1 Clever trick. Took the liberty of editing the answer to add some links to the VB6 reference manual. Usually I disapprove of DefType, Option Compare, etc because you have to look at the top of the module before you know what code is doing. But this is good.

Comment: You know, I was playing around with Option Compare last night, and I did find one interesting thing. If you need to sort or compare case-insensitively, Option Compare Text blows StrComp and LCase$ out of the water. By a lot. I hate to alter an entire module's compare method, but for certain heavy duty applications this could be a gain worth taking advantage of.